# How to show a particular set $S$ is a basis for $M_{2\times 2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given a set $S$ of four $2\times 2$ matrices with numbers in them and need to show they are a basis for $M_{2\times 2}$. all I know is that the linear combination of these matrices $= [0,0,0,0]$ must only have a solution of a scalar * each of them being 0. All I can think of is making a set of $4$ vectors and using that to test LI somehow. but how exactly am I allowed to make these vectors? Is this even the right method?

also, given another particular $2\times 2$ matrix, how would I figure out how to write it as a linear combination of the $4$ matrices in the set $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform them to coordinate vectors and then your matrix will be converted in form (a,b,c,d) (i,e vector). then procceed with usual method of checking L.I ,by checking determinant or whatever

I  highly recommend following for complete understanding of subject

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7w7ZrTZ-pWWk4-AOkiGEGp

[image: SEE PROBLEM 8]

[image]

Comment: so I could for example write out each matrix as a column by placing the elements clockwise from top to bottom, then take the determinant of the matrix from these 4 columns?

Comment: @JL yes this is correct . But reason u can do this is because u have converted ur matrix into coordinate vectors .

Comment: i see. thanks! So if I'm given another 2x2 matrix and I have to write it as a linear combination of the vectors in S, would I set the 4x4 matrix to a column derived from the 2x2 with the same method and then solve for the 4 scalars?

Comment: wait im editing my  answer .

Comment: @JL See problem 8.140

Comment: For page 223 instead of basis they have given u would take standard basis for 2 by 2 matrices . then constants u have to determine will be ur elements of matrix ,but for general procedure i have uploaded it

Comment: I see. It appears that is a more formal method of which I guessed. thanks!

Comment: Also pls note here they have to solve equations .But in ur case u need not to because the constants will be entries of matrix as u have stated earlier . I f basis would be different (given in Q) ,They u would have to use procedure shown in pics .Once u have got converted ur matrix to vectors then u can check them by making determinant as u have said .

Answer (score 1):

You can make the transformation of a matrix $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to the vector in $\mathbb{R^4}$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
\end{pmatrix}

You can then determine if the four vectors are linearly independent.